# Can't bind click event to a class set of elements

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I've got an image modal that will work when I bind an event handler to an Id, but not when I apply it to a class to have it fire off of any image clicked.

Here is a portion of the html

```
<div class="column">
  <img src="images/journalism-images/j1.jpg" class="grid-img" id="myImage">
  <img src="images/journalism-images/j2.jpg" class="grid-img">
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript below

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var images = document.getElementById("myImage");
var close = document.querySelector(".image-modal-close");

function changeImage() {
img.src = modalImg.src;
}

images.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
changeImage();
}
```

so basically what is happening is whatever image I put the ID of #myImage on will fire the modal with the correct image src, but I can't fire the modal when I use something like-

```
document.querySelectorAll(".grid-img");
```

can anyone help me out?

Comment: If you have `jquery`, just use `jquery`

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a set of elements, not a single one. You'll need to loop over the result and attach the events individually. Also, use `addEventListener()` to attach events, not the `onclick` property

Comment: ^^ That, of course, but in this instance I agree with @Eddie that if you're already using jQuery then this is simpler with that.  Do you want vanilla JS or would you be happy with jQuery?

Comment: or use ```querySelector() ``` to get the first matched element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-img");
for ( var index = 0; index < images.length; index ++ ) {
    images[index].addEventListener("click",function(e) {
        // Do whatever you need.
    },false);
}
```

Or

```
var $images = $( '.grid-img' );
$images.on( 'click', function(e) {
    // Do whatever you need.
});
```

Remember that `querySelectorAll` returns set of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery for this:

```
$(".grid-img").on("click", function() {
      //logic
}
```

`QuerySelectorAll` will return a **set of elements**.

If you want javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("grid-img").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    //Your logic
}
```

You can also watch the [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbyclassname) of `getElementsByClassName`

**Example of `getElementsByClassBame`:**

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-img");

element[0].addEventListener("click",function(e) {
        //Your logic
}
element[1].addEventListener("click",function(e) {
        //Your logic
}
```

Comment: Dev tools throws me an error with this function provided.


   `code` document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function

Comment: Look at the link I posted, if you want to use native js, you will have to access the elements as an array. I will post an example.